# Associativity of an operation

Tags: linear-algebra

How I can verify that this operation is associative ?, defined this way: $a+b=ab$ where $a$ and $b$ belong to $\mathbb{R^+}$

Comment: One (or both) of the two operations is not the usual one, because $a+b\neq ab$ in general in $\mathbb{R}^+$. if you mean $a\oplus b:=ab$, then of course $(a\oplus b)\oplus c=a\oplus (b\oplus c)$, because $(ab)c=a(bc)$ in real numbers.

Comment: I tried to check it for 3 positive real elements but do not see how to relate. If you have absolutely right, but this is an exercise to check that it is vector space, and I checked the other axioms with the other operation, I have only problems with this

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thank you very much has already clarified the doubt, very kind of you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this unusual operation I see that you have to check is that:

$(a+b)+c=(ab)c=a(bc)=a+(bc)=a+(b+c)$  this is because a, b and c are positive real numbers and this field is associative for the product and the addition and obviously you have defined the operation on, which is not usual.